# tmux died and says "no sessions" - is there any way to recover?

Tags: tmux

This sucks.

```
$ tmux attach-session
no sessions
```

My sysadmin upgraded tmux and now I can't reattach. My processes are still running according to `ps ux`. Is there any hope of recovering my session?

**Update**: There's a socket in `/tmp/tmux-1234`, so I tried `tmux -L /tmp/tmux-1234/default attach`, but tmux does nothing. Hooray.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

This quickest way to determine if you can recover is:

```
killall -10 tmux
```

That will send the signal to recreate all socket files for any running tmux processes.  If you're not root, no problem it will only signal your tmux process anyway.

Long story short, if tmux is not running (ps xu | grep tmux), you're screwed :(

Comment: This works, but I was confused about *why* it works. It turns out that signal 10 is a _user-defined signal_, and [tmux says it will "recreate the server socket on SIGUSR1"](https://github.com/ThomasAdam/tmux/blob/814e40522cb611895e84fc2aaf58d5d0ca9ba348/CHANGES#L552).

Comment: As it might help others: I had to find the PID of the tmux process running my lost session and do `kill -10 "PID"`.

Comment: (1) Thanks for this answer, it saved me a ton of work :) (2) I think it would be helpful to mention that the messages you get when another user is also running tmux, namely `tmux(12345): Operation not permitted`, are expected.

Comment: @DaoWen according to man signal (7), the signal value 10 does correspond to SIGUSR1, so all is well

Answer (score 2):

tmux is not guaranteed to be compatible across updates; ask your sysadmin to let you know before doing upgrades or use a copy you built locally that he is less likely to mess with.

Answer (score 0):

Some updates to h0tw1r3's answer.

I encountered this error when using the following command to create named tmux sessions:

```shell
tmux -CC -L my-session-name
```

You can list the existing sessions on Ubuntu Linux 20.04 with (as root):

```shell
ls -lha /tmp/tmux-0
```

Or

```shell
pf -Af|grep -i tmux
```

Then you can send signal SIGUSER1 or 10 to tmux with:

```
pkill -f 10 tmux
```

Then you can try to attach

```shell
tmux -CC -L my-session-name attach
```

If you are still getting

```
tmux failed with error: “no sessions”
```

Make sure you are spelling your session name as the same as it is under `ps -Af|grep -i tmux`